# Deploying to Azure Web App from Visual Studio Team Services empty Web App Location drop down

Tags: azure, deployment, tfs, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to configure automated deployments for my MVC app that uses npm and gulp from Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) using Git to an Azure Web App. I have configured the build steps in Team Services and the build works fine, but I can't figure out how to configure deployment to Azure. The Web App Location dropdown is empty and I'm not even sure what it is supposed to be.  Any help would be great.

[image]

Here was my solution, you can just type the name of the location (geographical region) and app name ({appname}.azurewebsites.net), you can specify the Web Deploy Package in your build solution step:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your scenario, there is no dropdown list in Web App Location. You can try to type the location in `Web App Location` and type a name for the website in `Web App Name`. The location you can refer to App Service Location in Azure when create a Web App:

[image]

[image]

Comment: this got me going in the right direction, I'll add my solution to the question.  thank you!